# How to install TWRP on to Huawei P9 Eva-l09

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, fastboot, huawei, flashtool

Hi does anyone have experience installing **TWRP** on a **Huawei P9 Eva-l09**, ive **FRP locked** my phone on factory reset and don't know the old account, i've **unlocked** the **bootloader** but when I run the command from the **Fastboot** to flash the **Official Eva TWRP img** I get an error

```
E:\Downloads\huawei>fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.1.1-1-eva.img
target reported max download size of 471859200 bytes
sending 'recovery' (25282 KB)...
OKAY [  0.552s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: image verification error)
finished. total time: 0.571s
```

From research on other places I've found that it has something to do with how it writes to the partition as I've also tried

> recovery_ramdisk

and had another error saying that the partition file size is wrong.

```
E:\Downloads\huawei>fastboot flash recovery_ramdisk twrp-3.1.1-1-eva.img
target reported max download size of 471859200 bytes
sending 'recovery_ramdisk' (25282 KB)...
OKAY [  0.552s]
writing 'recovery_ramdisk'...
FAILED (remote: partition length get error)
finished. total time: 0.564s
```

If anyone could assist me in the install or show me a guide on how they did it I would appreciate it as I cant find the answer anywhere

Comment: guess it's caused by FRP. maybe ask in [support](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3565703) thread

Comment: https://forum.dc-unlocker.com/forum/modems-and-phones/huawei/158868-fastboot-failed-remote-image-verification-error check your *'fastboot devices'* serialno. check *'fastboot oem get-bootinfo'* + *'fastboot oem get-lockstate'* https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3714581